# Canvas has Width of 0 after adding children. How to cause canvas to recalculate width?

Tags: c#, wpf, layout

I'm creating a custom canvas which has dynamically added shapes (lines) which are added as children.  Unfortunately, after adding the children, the canvas has a width of 0, which is not expected.
Ideally, the canvas should update its width by using its children's dimensions.

**How can I modify my canvas to account for the dimensions of its children, and then update its width?**

As I said, I changed the shapes on the canvas dynamically.  I do this every time one of its dependency properties is changed using a callback function.

Generally, this is what that callback function looks like:
*This is not my algorithm, but it should demonstrate the point.*

```
public void UpdateLines()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_BARS; i++)
    {
        Line bar = new Line();
        bar.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        bar.StrokeThickness = 4;
        bar.X1 = 0;
        bar.X2 = ActualWidth;
        bar.Y1 = i * (bar.StrokeThickness + 2);
        bar.Y1 = bar.Y2;
        this.Children.Add(bar);
    }

    //[Inserted here]
}
```

The next thing I noticed is that I could add a line with a large length, and that line would appear, but the canvas width would still remain 0.

At the "Inserted Here" mark, I put this line of code to test:

```
Children.Add(new Line() { Stroke=Brushes.Black, 
                          StrokeThickness = 4, X1 = 0, X2 = 200, Y1 = 10, Y2 = 10 });
```

**So, why the canvas width is not updating properly?**  I need to use it for calculating the size of my lines.

Your help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: A `Canvas` is not a panel type that automatically grows to accommodate the size of its children, so if the `Canvas.GetLeft(Child) + Child.Width` is greater than the `Canvas.Width`, you need to tell it to grow by increasing it's `.Width` yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the [Panels Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for further help with WPF `Panel`s, but in short, the `Canvas Panel` does *not* resize itself when child items are added (or at any time).  From the linked page:

> Canvas is not affected by the size of its children. As a result, it is possible for a child element to overdraw other elements outside the bounding rectangle of the parent Canvas.

Therefore, you will either need to manually update the size of the `Canvas`, or use a different type of layout `Panel` that *does* resize itself when child items are added, although the `Canvas` is the only `Panel` that enables users to place child controls at absolute positions within it.

Again, from the linked page:

> Canvas  provides the most flexible layout support of any Panel. Height and Width properties are used to define the area of the canvas, and elements inside are assigned absolute coordinates relative to the area of the parent Canvas. Four attached properties, Canvas.Left, Canvas.Top, Canvas.Right and Canvas.Bottom, allow fine control of object placement within a Canvas, allowing the developer to position and arrange elements precisely on the screen.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.  I have another question about the reverse process (because my lines need to update based on the width).  Do you know if it is possible for the canvas width to update based on specifying margin/alignment information?  I figured that would cause the initial width to be non-zero.

Comment: You can only update the `Width` of the `Canvas` using the `Canvas.Width` property. Read the *ClipToBounds Within a Canvas* section of the linked page... that might help.